# Turn off prelude intellisense

Tags: company-mode, auto-complete-mode, prelude

In emacs prelude ruby mode, how I tell emacs to not do intellisense dropdown suggestions?

It breaks my flow. Because I have to press an additional key to break out of that menu.

What I tried: google "Turn off prelude intellisense"

Comment: You are probably looking for `company-mode` or `auto-complete-mode`.

Comment: are you the dan Davison mentioned at  http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/ ?  @Dan

Comment: Nope!  Sorry to disappoint. ;)